# android-java: check boolean value checking for null

Tags: java, android

I am trying for null check  like below

```
if (isTrue == null)
```

compile error says : "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean"

Please help, how to do null check.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do `null` check on primitive types. `boolean` is a primitive type.

If you absolutely need to represent a `null` value with a `boolean` variable, you need to use the wrapper class `java.lang.Boolean`.

So, your example would be:

```
Boolean isTrue;
isTrue = null; // valid
isTrue = true; // valid
isTrue = false; // valid
if (isTrue == null) {
    // valid!
}
```

[Here's the WIKIPEDIA entry for primitive wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Answer (score 7):

The right way is

```
boolean isTrue;
if(!isTrue)
```

or

```
if(isTrue)
```

You can not check if the boolean is null or not.boolean must be true or false.

Answer (score 4):

A boolean is a primative type and cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean cannot be null in java.

A Boolean, however, can be null.